# Jasmine test the result returned from a then function

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

My code:

```
$scope.someFunction = function(){
    var urls = ["someurl", "someOtherUrl"]

    return $q.all(urls).then(function(response){
         return "PASS"
    })
}
```

How do I test that the result is "PASS"?

I've tried the following:

```
var deferred = _$q_.defer();
spyOn($q, 'all').and.returnValue(deferred.promise);

var results = "FAIL"
deferred.resolve(results);

$q.all().then(function(a){
    expect(a).toBe("PASS") // -- this doesn't work
    expect(a).toBe("FAIL") // -- this does work but is not what we want to test;
});
```

Please help

Answer (score 0):

There's no reason to mangle $q at all (also, stubbing it will make the code untestable).

It`s returned promise that should just be tested:

```
var promise = scope.someFunction();
promise.then(function (result) {
  expect(result).toBe('PASS')
});
$rootScope.$digest();
```

[jasmine-promise-matchers](https://github.com/bvaughn/jasmine-promise-matchers) is more convenient way to test $q promises.